# How to calculate end-points of a line whose orientation aligns with real horizon using Android Sensor data

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'd like to calculate two points that align with the real horizon (presuming the user is holding the device virtually).  I'd like the line connecting those 2 points to pass through a center point of my choosing.

I'm collecting `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` vectors and have found sample code to rotate bitmaps with rotationmatrix but can't get my mind around calculating just the 2 points I need in terms of the screen's X and Y.

Any hints greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comments. The more I thought about it, the more my head hurt. So you mean the second of my comments - the user always sees a horizontal line regardless of tilt left / right?

Comment: Yes, that describes it. @Squonk

Comment: What about tilt forward / back as well as left / right? That's going to need 3D geometry. I could probably manage the maths required for just left / right but I'm rusty when it comes to 3D geometry.

Comment: Not sure what's involved with the calculation so I don't know if it needs 3D geometry but the final effect is 2D, basically what I want is 2D the way a bubble level is 2D, so I don't care about tilt.   That makes me think, I never searched for "android bubble level" code... looking now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood everything right, that should be an easy trigonometric question.
You should find the angle to horizon and then It will look like this

[image]

X1 = 0

Y1 = Yc + Xc * tan(a)

X2 = screenWidth

Y2 = Yc - (screenWidth - Xc) * tan(a)

Comment: That did it, I the orientation[-2] value from a call to sensorManager.getOrientation(remapedRotationM, orientation) gave me angle for the above trig.  Thanks!